# Right way to deploy to JBoss Fuse from Nexus?

Tags: maven, jboss, nexus, jbossfuse

I have a few JBoss projects, with versions in POM set to 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
JBoss is setup with Nexus snapshot repository as remote repository in org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg, like so:

```
org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories= \
http://localhost:8888/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/@snapshots@id=nexus.repo
```

In my POMs, I use the Nexus Maven plugin to deploy the built artifacts to Nexus, with "mvn clean deploy", like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.7</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
    <serverId>nexus</serverId>
    <nexusUrl>http://localhost:8888/nexus/</nexusUrl>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Latest artifact gets into Nexus just fine. So I deploy to Fuse with this:

```
$FUSE_BIN/client "osgi:install -s mvn:my.package/my-service/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
$FUSE_BIN/client "osgi:update my-service mvn:my.package/my-service/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

However, it updates the service using the cached version from the "localRepository", instead of downloading the latest. So am I supposed to:

1) Update the version in the POM every time I use "mvn deploy"

2) Purge the localRepository before I use osgi:update

3) Something I've configured wrong?

Isn't the localRepository supposed to know when the cached artifact is different from Nexus?

Answer (score 0):

You're installing an already-installed artifact (I don't se any uninstall going on in your code) with the same version. It's perfectly legit to reuse the "local" artifact.

If you wish JBoss Fuse to "reload" an artifact, you should tell it to do it.

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root> dev:watch 372
Watched URLs/IDs:
371
372
```

Now when you deploy a newer `-SNAPSHOT`, JBoss Fuse will reload it.

Reference: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Console_Reference/files/ConsoleDevWatch.html

Comment: That isn't working for me, when I deploy a new snapshot of the artifact to Nexus, Fuse isn't reloading it. When I run osgi:install on the new snapshot (not supposed to but it's not reloading), it's installed alongside the previous version. Perhaps nothing's triggering the update to localRepository?